# Is async await inappropriate for achieving dynamic parallelism?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm writing a service that will run on ASP.NET Core (2.2). The work performed within the context of a request/response is highly CPU-intensive, and there is no reliance on I/O or other network-based services.  Due to the nature of the work being performed, dynamic parallelism seems like the best approach. It is not a matter of invoking Parallel.ForEach, but rather, creating and running tasks as necessary.

That's the background.  What I haven't managed to figure out is this:
Is there an advantage or disadvantage to using the await async pattern? I can create Tasks and wait for them using blocking calls such as Task.WaitAll and Task.WaitAny, or I can create Tasks and await them using non-blocking calls such as Task.WhenAll and Task.WhenAny.

I've seen advice on various websites (and most notably in Stephen Cleary's book "Concurrency in C# Cookbook", chapter 3.4) to use the Task.Wait* methods to achieve dynamic parallelism, but I don't quite understand why. Is there an inherent advantage to using blocking calls when doing dynamic parallelism?  Wouldn't the async/await approach offer its own advantage by freeing up the calling Task while it awaits the called Task to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic parallelism predates `async` and `await`, and it is commonly done in a part of the code where blocking is desired, but you *can* `await` a CPU-bound task just like you can `await` an I/O-bound task.

In my experience, most of the time dynamic parallelism uses `AttachedToParent`, which kind of gives the task an implicit wait for all of its children. Not an actual `Wait`, since a thread is not blocked, but a more `await`-style kind of `Wait`. For this reason, I don't use `await` explicitly within my dynamic parallelism code. But it *is* common to have a single top-level `await` if you don't want to block the calling thread.

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  The approach I'm taking won't be using AttachedToParent,

Comment: Accidentally hit "Enter" on the above comment....  
OK.  That makes sense.  The approach I'm taking won't be using AttachedToParent. Instead, I create quite a few Tasks (frequently more Tasks than CPU's), where the Tasks must wait for "pre-computation" Tasks to finish before they can do their own computations.  This led me to take the await/async approach.  Given that setup, what I'm hearing from you is that awaiting CPU-bound tasks in this manner shouldn't be a problem.  Correct?

Comment: Another option is to pseud-manage the tasks your self. I'm not saying make a whole task scheduler but take advantage of the Task tools provided by .net
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3152735/my-two-cents-on-the-task-waitall-and-task-whenall-methods.html

Comment: If you're not using `AttachedToParent`, you could either use `await` or `ContinueWith` to have one task depend on another. I'm not sure which would be better in this case, but if you mix them, be especially wary of wrapped tasks (e.g., `Task<Task>`).